# Pedometers and setting stride length from your height?

Tags: regression, standard-error

**A question I originally asked in the [Fitness forum](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/23711/pedometers-and-setting-stride-length-from-your-height-how-accurate), but closed as maths apparently has nothing to do with Fitness / is off-topic:**

Just looking at a couple of pedometer instruction leaflets, from different manufacturers, and spotted that they both suggest you can approximate your stride length from your height via the following formula:

> females = 0.413 * height
>
> males = 0.415 * height

A quick Google implies the formula were originally proposed in the following paper:

***Hatano, Y. "Use of the pedometer for promoting daily walking exercise." Int. Council Health Phys. Educ. Recreat. 29:4 – 8, 1993.***

Anyway I'm trying to find out how accurate the above equations are (standard deviation / error), and if there are any alternate regression equations out there that include: weight, age, leg length, foot size.... to reduce the error?

Comment: As stated, you are asking for reference papers on how to improve predictive models of stride length. As such, this looks off-topic on this site, unless you have a specific question at hand.

Comment: While it's true that this is more a question about a content domain than about data analysis, and hence not a good fit for this site, I feel bad because it's a great question and was turned down by a site where it really ought to have fit (pun not intended). You might try http://skeptics.stackexchange.com. I think investigating the truth of those "articles… kicking around the web" may be up their alley.

Comment: For this question to stay open here, you'll need to ask a specific question with statistical content. Your present post seems to be a scattergun of issues. I suggest you edit to ask about one thing that is clearly statistical. For example, discussing articles that suggest pedometers are a waste of time don't seem to relate to a specific statistical issue.

Comment: Removed the references to the articles that summarize some of the research on pedometer accuracy, will limit the questions scope to just stride length eg.  http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1810544/  or http://www.researchgate.net/profile/Melanie_Bell2/publication/8482514_Commercially_available_pedometers_considerations_for_accurate_step_counting/links/0fcfd509c29bbcec67000000.pdf OR   http://bmb.oxfordjournals.org/content/95/1/121.full